# JVM property -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 or UTF-8?

Tags: file, encoding, utf-8, jvm

I would like to know what is the value of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) property to set my file encoding to UTF-8.

Do I put `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` or `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Anyway, it works for me:)

Answer (score 63):

It will be:

```
UTF8
```

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) for the definitions.

Comment: in fact, I have already seen this page. But, I didn't know which of the "Canonical Name for java.nio API" or the "Canonical Name for java.io and java.lang API" I must use.

Comment: Both work but `UTF-8` is preferred over `UTF8` - the only standard format.

Comment: When using Spring Boot try "UTF-8". It worked in my case.

Comment: See my answer for why I favour `UTF-8`, since it pops up for all kinds of defaults in the JDK.

Comment: This answer says `UTF8` without hyphen - the comments to this answer, however, advise to use the hyphanated form `UTF-8`. Not very helpful.

Comment: I see nothing in your link to justify your assertion that "_It will be UTF8_". You could just as easily have stated "_It will be UTF-8_" based on that documentation. Can you explain why you specified "_UTF8_"?

Comment: I've tested both UTF8 and UTF-8 and it appears to give me the same result in my build.

Comment: `UTF8`, `UTF-16`, `UTF_32`...

Answer (score 25):

If, running an Oracle HotSpot JDK 1.7.x, on a Linux platform where your locale suggests UTF-8 (e.g. `LANG=en_US.utf8`), if you don't set it on the command-line with `-Dfile.encoding`, the JDK will default `file.encoding` and the default `Charset` like this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("file.encoding: %s", System.getProperty("file.encoding")));
System.out.println(String.format("defaultCharset: %s", Charset.defaultCharset().name()));
```

... yields:

```
file.encoding: UTF-8
defaultCharset: UTF-8
```

... suggesting the default is `UTF-8` on such a platform.

Additionally, if `java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset()` finds `file.encoding` not-set, it looks for `java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8")`, suggesting it prefers that string, although it is well-aliased, so "UTF8" will also work fine.

If you run the same program on the same platform with `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8`, without the hypen, it yields:

```
file.encoding: UTF8
defaultCharset: UTF-8
```

... noting that the default charset has been canonicalized from `UTF8` to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 11):

Both UTF8 and UTF-8 work for me.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a direct answer, but very useful if you don't have access to how java starts: you can set the environment variable `JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS` to `-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"` and every time the jvm starts it will pick up that option.