# Parsing PDF with russian text and tabula-py returns ???? in result. ( on windows)

Tags: python-3.x, tabula

I am on Windows 7 32 bit. When I parse russian text PDF i recieve results file with ??? instead of russian characters.
The developer addresses this issue with this fix

> I got ? character with result on Windows. How can I avoid it? If the
>   encoding of PDF is UTF-8, you should set chcp 65001 on your terminal
>   before launching a Python process.
>
> chcp 65001

I changed this in windows cmd but with no resul.

my code

```
import tabula


tabula.convert_into(r"C:\Code\Active\kartoteka\misc\ExampleExtract.pdf", r"C:\Code\Active\kartoteka\misc\output.csv", output_format="csv",pages = "all",java_options="-Dfile.encoding=utl-8")
```

Error log:

```
?? 10, 2018 11:15:18 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2Font getawtFont
INFO: Can't read the embedded font Times-Roman
??? 10, 2018 11:15:18 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2Font getawtFont
INFO: Using font Times New Roman instead
??? 10, 2018 11:15:19 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2Font getawtFont
INFO: Can't read the embedded font Times-Roman
??? 10, 2018 11:15:19 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2Font getawtFont
INFO: Using font Times New Roman instead
```

My resulting file still shows all russian characters in ?????
How do you fix this issue?

Thats how original PDF looks.
[image]

Comment: Is it correct java_options or typo? It should be `java_options="-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"`. see also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031877/jvm-property-dfile-encoding-utf8-or-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

*Nota bene: my comment is regarding the ability to extract text properly from a PDF in general versus tablula-py specifically, but hopefully this helps you determine if the problem lies with your PDF or with your PDF software.*

It's difficult to comment on the file you are looking at without seeing it but a good starting point is to try Acrobat and by either copying the text and pasting it into a text editor or doing a search for the text content will reveal if it can be extracted correctly or not.

If it can't be extracted properly then there's a good chance the font is lacking a ToUnicode entry (see Section 9.10.1 of the ISO PDF 32000-1:2008 specification for more information).

If Acrobat can extract the text properly then it's possible there is an issue with the PDF software you are using.