# Different codepoints for same character in MacOS and Windows

Tags: java, string, unicode, utf-8, windows-1252

I have a small piece of code in which I am checking the codepoint for the the character `Ü`.

```
Locale lc = Locale.getDefault();
System.out.println(lc.toString());
System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
String inUnicode = "\u00dc";
String glyph = "Ü";
System.out.println("inUnicode " + inUnicode + " code point " + inUnicode.codePointAt(0));
System.out.println("glyph " + glyph + " code point " + glyph.codePointAt(0));
```

I am getting different value for codepoint when I run this code on MacOS x  and Windows 10, see the output below.

Output on MacOS

```
en_US
UTF-8
UTF-8
inUnicode Ü code point 220
glyph Ü code point 220
```

Output on Windows

```
en_US
windows-1252
Cp1252
in unicode Ü code point 220
glyph ?? code point 195
```

I checked the codepage for windows-1252 at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set, here the codepoint for `Ü` is `220`. 
For `String glyph = "Ü";` why do I get codepoint as `195` on Windows? As per my understanding `glyph` should have been rendered properly and the codepoint should have been `220` since it is defined in Windows-1252.

If I replace `String glyph = "Ü";` with `String glyph = new String("Ü".getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));` then `glyph` is rendered correctly and codepoint value is `220`.
Is this the correct and efficient way to standardize behavior of String on any OS irrespective of locale and charset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

195 is 0xC3 in hex.

In UTF-8, `Ü` is encoded as bytes `0xC3 0x9C`.

`System.getProperty("file.encoding")` says the default file encoding on Windows is not UTF-8, but clearly your Java file is actually encoded in UTF-8.  The fact that `println()` is outputting `glyph ??` (note 2 `?`, meaning 2 `char`s are present), and that you are able to decode the raw string bytes using the UTF-8 `Charset`, proves this.

`glyph` should have a single `char` whose value is `0x00DC`, not 2 `char`s whose values are `0x00C3 0x009C`.  `getCodepointAt(0)` is returning `0x00C3` (195) on Windows because your Java file is encoded in UTF-8 but is being loaded as if it were encoded in Windows-1252 instead, so the 2 bytes `0xC3 0x9C` get decoded as characters `0x00C3 0x009C` instead of as character `0x00DC`.

You need to specify the actual file encoding when running Java, eg:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why `195` is returned on windows. I tired `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` on Windows but it didn't work, `glyph` is still `??`. Although the flag did change the charset to `UTF-8`. Also `unicode.equals(glyph)` should ideally evaluate to `true` (which is the case on macOS),  but without decoding the raw string bytes using UTF-8 it evaluates to `false` on Windows.

Comment: "*I tired `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` on Windows but it didn't work, `glyph` is still `??`*" - it shouldn't be. That means it is still being processed as Windows-1252. Try `=UTF8` instead of `=UTF-8`, though [both should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031877/).

Comment: It seems like the character encoding had been cached. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding. I was able to get it working after setting the flag in environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`. Thanks again for the explanation. However, rather than using the flag isn't it better and safe option to use `getBytes`

Comment: @pradystar "*isn't it better and safe option to use `getBytes`*" - no, because the string contents have already been messed up, risking data loss, as soon as the source file is parsed in the wrong encoding, before you ever have a chance to call `getBytes()`. Best to tell Java the correct file encoding up front so the string contents are correct to begin with. `getBytes()` is a hack, not a real solution. If you don't want to fix the encoding, then you have to use `\u` escapes in your literals to avoid the issue altogether.